# AWS lambda: Is there a way to set default value if the environment variable doesn't exist in the log4j.xml?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, log4j, aws-sdk, aws-lambda-layers

I have aws lambda function implementation using java. I am using the standard log4j configuration to log into cloudwatch . I am able to access the aws lambda environment runtime variable into my log4j to set my log level. The only question I have - Is there a way we can default the log level to something in the absence of the environment variable value in the log4j.xml?

Below is the log4j.xml configuration I have.

```
< Loggers></br>
    < Root level="debug"><\br>
        < AppenderRef ref="Lambda" /><\br>
    < /Root><\br>
< /Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate to Log4j2 (currently supported by AWS Lambda, you can find details on [AWS GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-log4j2)), It has "Lookups" feature which allows to use environment variables in Log4j2 configuration file: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup

So you could use something like this in your configuration file: "${env:VAR_NAME:-info}", where -info would be a default logging level.